# gles glsl bit wise operations problems

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, bitwise-operators

I am trying to create a shader that uses bitwise commands for a mobile application. I am using glsl version 320 es. To demonstrate the problem I have created a shadertoy example:
https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MsVyRw
Which should show a red screen. The screen appears red when opened from my galaxy s8 as well. When running my application with the following fragment shader:

```
#version 320 es
precision highp float;
out vec4 fragColor;
void main()
{
    uint x = uint(0xec140e57);
    uint tmp0 = x >> uint(4);
    uint tmp1 = uint(0xec140e57) >> uint(4);
    if(tmp0 == tmp1){
        fragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0,1.0);
    }
    else{
        fragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0,1.0);
    }
};
```

The screen appears blue. However if I change

```
uint x = uint(0xec140e57);
uint tmp0 = x >> uint(4);
uint tmp1 = uint(0xec140e57) >> uint(4);
```

to

```
uint tmp0 = uint(0xec140e57) >> uint(4);
uint tmp1 = uint(0xec140e57) >> uint(4);
```

the screen appears red.

It is definitely not a problem with the gpu ALUs since it works with shadertoy. Is there something that I am missing with the preprocessor flags that would allow this sort of operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragment shaders have a default `int` precision of `mediump`, so I suspect you have precision problems (literals at 32-bit precision, and variables at 16-bit precision). See Shader Language Spec section 4.7.4.

Try adding `precision highp int;` to the start of the shader along with the other default precision statements.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This was actually half the problem. So I did try this before and it didn't fix the problem. What was happening is that when I did uint(....) >> x the default precision assigned wasn't applying for some reason. But when I assigned it to a variable first it was working as intended. Actually on most devices uint(...) >> x was causing a crash but I didn't realize that was the problem.